# Convert pure html5 cordova app to ionic

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid

I have completed an app written in regular html5 and I need that same app in ionic format, is there an easy way to convert this to ionic or atleast serve it from ionic terminal?

Comment: There is no way to "convert" it to Ionic. You need to start from scratch.

Comment: Is there a way to serve it from ionic, using something like an ionic iframe or something? @MarkoSavic

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to do that.... Try to move your code from app A to B and ask a question if you stuck somewhere. Good luck!